# Convert factor into integer based on frequency in R

Tags: r

A vector of factor:

```
vec <- factor(c('a','b','b','c','b','c'))
[1] a b b c b c                                                                                                                                                              
Levels: a b c
```

Would expect a new vector of

```
vec_new
[1] 3 1 1 2 1 2
```

The one with higher frequency will be converted to smaller integer.
Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: did you try anything? `as.numeric(factor(vec, levels = names(sort(table(vec), decreasing = TRUE))))`

Comment: Was trying `summary(vec)` and planning to extract frequency and names to a dataframe. but got stuck. Was working on a neater one. Yours is very neat. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
x2 <- rev(sort(table(x)))
names(x2) <- names(sort(table(x)))
levels(x) <- x2[order(names(x2))]
x
[1] 3 1 1 2 1 2
Levels: 3 1 2
```

We first find the highest frequency factor and reverse the order (smallest to largest) with `rev(sort(table(x)))`. Next we rename that smallest to largest vector to match the names of the regular largest to smallest frequency table. Lastly, we can now assign the new levels based on the order of the names while using the smallest to largest indices.

Another option courtesy of @RichardScriven:

```
s <- sort(table(x)) 
x <- factor(vec, labels = rev(s), levels = names(s))
```

**Data**

```
vec <- letters[c(1,2,2,3,2,3)]
x <- factor(vec)
[1] a b b c b c
Levels: a b c
```

Comment: Or it looks like `s <- sort(table(vec), decreasing = TRUE); factor(vec, labels = s, levels = rev(names(s))) ## [1] 3 1 1 2 1 2` would also work.  Same premise

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw in another one-liner:

```
as.numeric(reorder(vec, -ave(as.numeric(vec), vec, FUN = length)))
# [1] 3 1 1 2 1 2
```

First, you calculate the (negative - to have the proper ordering afterwards) frequency of each vector level with `ave`, then you reorder the factor levels with `reorder`. The latter calculates the mean of `-ave(.)` for each level and resorts the factor levels accordingly in increasing order (that's why we used `-ave(.)`). Finally, transform the factor into a numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there's a more efficient approach, but you you can find out how frequently different levels of the factor occur with `table(vec)`, and then you can manually order the levels of the factor with `levels(vec) <- c("b", "c", "a")`.

Comment: This is the right direction, thanks a lot. I think I got it.