# Easier way to calculate conditioned proportions with R data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say we have this toy example:

```
library(data.table)
temp <- data.table(first=c("A", "A","A", "A","B","C","C"), 
   sec=c("X", "X","X", "Y","X",  "Z","Z"), stringsAsFactors = T))

first sec
  A   X
  A   X
  A   X
  A   Y
  B   X
  C   Z
  C   Z
```

I would like to get a third column stating the proportion of times that combination happens among the occurrences of the first column.

I got to do it with data.table in the following way:

```
temp[,N1:=.N,by=.(first, sec)]
temp[,N2:=.N,by=first]
temp[, prop := N1/N2]
temp[,c("N1","N2"):=NULL]


first sec prop
   A   X 0.75
   A   X 0.75
   A   X 0.75
   A   Y 0.25
   B   X 1.00
   C   Z 1.00
   C   Z 1.00
```

That means that A,X happens 3 times. A happens 4 times, thus AX happens the 75% of the time the first letter is A.

Couldn't that be done easier?

Kind of

```
temp[,.N(first,sec)/.N(first)]
```

Answer (score 5):

What about doing grouping inside each first-level group with `ave`:

```
temp[, prop := ave(as.numeric(sec), sec, FUN = length) / .N, by = .(first)]
# > temp
#    first sec prop
# 1:     A   X 0.75
# 2:     A   X 0.75
# 3:     A   X 0.75
# 4:     A   Y 0.25
# 5:     B   X 1.00
# 6:     C   Z 1.00
# 7:     C   Z 1.00
```

Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32003058/3926543

Another way: chain commands:

```
temp[,N:=.N,by=.(first, sec)][, prop := N / .N, by = .(first)][, N := NULL]
```

**when `first` and `sec` have many levels and `temp` has many more rows, 
chaining commands or the solution in OP's question will be faster than `ave` solution.**

Comment: but ave it's not a data.table function. Wouldn't that be much slower?

Comment: I've tried temp[, prop2 := temp[,N:=.N,by=.(first, sec)]$N / .N, by = .(first)]  but strangely only works when you run it twice.

Comment: @skan, for the strange error, althgough run twice will give results, the results are wrong. I suggest that you do it in chain `temp[,N:=.N,by=.(first, sec)][, prop2 := N / .N, by = .(first)]`.

Comment: you could also add the temp[,N := .N, by=.(first, sec)][, prop:=N/.N, by=.(first)] solution to the benchmark, it's almost as fast as the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative. It is not simpler, in my mind, but sort of embodies the idea that you have. The idea is to count the separate values of sec within first using `table`, return the proportion and the corresponding value of sec, drop counts that are 0, and then join the returned data.table onto the original.

```
temp[temp[, {cnt=table(sec); .(sec=names(cnt), prop=c(cnt) / .N)}, by=first][prop > 0],
     on=c("first", "sec")]
   first sec prop
1:     A   X 0.75
2:     A   X 0.75
3:     A   X 0.75
4:     A   Y 0.25
5:     B   X 1.00
6:     C   Z 1.00
7:     C   Z 1.00
```